# How to output a 2-D matrix from a neural network in Keras with softmax applying for each column?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to implement a neural network, which output a 2-D matrix with softmax activation for each column.

I have done this with the code below, but it seems very slow when the number of columns increase.

```
input = Input(shape=[100])
h1 = Dense(200, activation='relu')(input)
output = []
for i in range(n_cols):
    output.append(Dense(n_rows, activation='softmax')(h1))
outputs = concatenate(output, axis=1)
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
```

Could someone suggest to me faster ways? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which are known to be *generally* faster than for-loops.

Instead of:

```
output = []
for i in range(n_cols):
    output.append(Dense(n_rows, activation='softmax')(h1))
```

You might try:

```
output = [(Dense(n_rows, activation='softmax')(h1)) for i in range(n_cols)]
```

In general, though, the more columns you add, the slower it'll be.

Comment: Thank you, it's a bit faster, but it's still slow when the number of columns are large. Do you have any idea of processing in matrix, such as softmax over all columns in the output?

Comment: Not that I know of. You might look into using one of Keras' backends instead of Keras.